# how to change take photo text to retake photo text when there is image

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am working on one camera app. There is one button called `Take Photo` where user can take photo and it will show in below of that button.

What i need is. Once i took picture n=and when photo is show under take photo button. I want to change the text from take photo to retake photo. If no images are available i need to show take photo text. How to do that ?

Here my code `html` :

```
 <button class="button button-energized" ng-click="getPhoto()">
      Take Photos
  </button>
  <div class="spacer" style="height: 10px;" ></div>

  <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <img ng-src="{{lastPhoto}}" style="max-width: 70%;max-height: 70%;">

  </div>
```

**My controller code :**

```
 $scope.getPhoto = function() {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-show** or **ng-if** for this

```
<button class="button button-energized" ng-click="getPhoto()"><span ng-if="!lastPhoto ">Take Photos</span><span ng-if="lastPhoto">Retake Photo</span></button>
```

Comment: sorry actually i wrongly sent url.This i solved already. My actual post is here this only i struck more hrs.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985247/how-to-convert-my-image-to-data-url-and-then-to-send-to-db

Comment: can u please help me out

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014164/how-to-convert-iamge-to-data-uri-ionic