# how to check the toggle button on/off state ionic to send to db

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have one text called `Developer` = `toggle button on/off`. So user can do `on/off` with the toggle button. But in same screen I have one button called `submit`. So while submitting I need to sent whether user has `on/off` or `checked/unchecked` the developer option and I need to sent that to db.

So like `[ developer: yes/1/ON/ ]`  like this. How can i do that. If user checked the toggle button i need to keep as yes or no.

Here is my code :

```
<label class="item item-input " style="height: 50px;"><span class="input-labels-over"><font style="color:#696969; padding-top: 0px;">Claim</font></span>
    <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm"></ion-toggle>
</label>
```

My controller code :

```
$scope.submit = function() {}
```

I am stuck more than 2 hr. I am new to `ionic`.

If user checked means to db I need to sent *yes*. If user didn't checked the toggle button I need to sent *no* to db.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Und3rTow   can you help me with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975220/how-to-change-take-photo-text-to-retake-photo-text-when-there-is-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ng-model**

```
<label class="item item-input " style="height: 50px;"><span class="input-labels-over"><font style="color:#696969; padding-top: 0px;">Claim</font></span<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-model="data.toggle"></ion-toggle></label>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.data = {}
$scope.submit = function() {
 var toggleStatus = $scope.data.toggle //return true or false
 //your code
}
```

Comment: Ok. but to db i need to send if its checked i need to send as `1` . If its not checked i need to sent that `2` . How can i handle that ??

Comment: i have one more question. NO solution for that also. Here my code   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975220/how-to-change-take-photo-text-to-retake-photo-text-when-there-is-image

Comment: you can check with condition...
 var toggleStatus =  $scope.data.toggle:1?2