# How to convert iamge to data uri ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, camera, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using one camera app. In that after i took photot i need to convert that image to data uri and then have to send to db.

here is what i did :

```
function opencamer() {

   console.log("camer open");
   Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
      $scope.imgUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });


}
```

but when i sent this `$scope.imgUrl` to db. i was not able to get data uri.please help me out how can i solve this.

i am truck more than 3 hr. not able to find solution.please help me out.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
    $scope.opencamer= function () {
              var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI)                    {
                  $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
                 $scope.imgUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;     


                }, function (err) {
                    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                });
            }
```

send `$scope.lastPhoto` to your db instead of `$scope.imgUrl`

Comment: in controller should i need to mention camera or $cordovaCamera .

Comment: now i have mentioned camera.Then when i tap opencamera.its not opening ?

Comment: i checked . i also installed the plugins too. but too camera is no opening

Comment: You need to add `ng-cordova` to your project and inject `$cordovaCamera` to your controller

Comment: i tried. but camera not at all opening. And why should i need to give $scope.lastPhoto to your db instead of $scope.imgUrl. does $scope.lastPhoto is already a base64 url ?

Comment: i was not able to add ng-cordova in my app.js. but in my index.html i have `    <script src="cordova.js"></script>`. and i inject `$cordovaCamera`. but camera is not at all opening

Comment: install `ng-cordova` with `$ bower install ngCordova` and add `ng-cordova.min.js` in index.html before `cordova.js`  `<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: Its because ng-cordova is not available.Please follow steps in my above comment..Or check this link..http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/